# terraform "element" and "concat" used together

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform

we have a module that builds a security proxy that hosts an elasticsearch site using terraform. In its code there is this;

```
elastic_search_endpoint = "${element(concat(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint, list("")),0)}"
```

which as I understand, then goes and finds the es_cluster module and gets the elasticsearch endpoint that was outputted from that. This then allows the proxy to have this endpoint available so it can run elasticsearch.

But I don't actually understand what this piece of code is doing and why the 'element' and 'concat' functions are there. Why can't it just be like this?

```
elastic_search_endpoint = "${module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint}"
```

Comment: It is probably an archaic type conversion pattern from Terraform <= 0.11.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this up and see what each part does.

It's not shown in the example, but I'm going to assume that `module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint` is an output value that is a list of eitehr zero or one ElasticSearch endpoints, presumably because that module allows disabling the generation of an ElasticSearch endpoint.

If so, that means that `module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint` would either be `[]` (empty list) or `["es.example.com"]`.

Let's consider the case where it's a one-element list first: `concat(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint, list(""))` in that case will produce the list `["es.example.com", ""]`. Then `element(..., 0)` will take the first element, giving `"es.example.com"` as the final result.

In the empty-list case, `concat(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint, list(""))` produces the list `[""]`. Then `element(..., 0)` will take the first element, giving `""` as the final result.

Given all of this, it seems like the intent of this expression is to either return the one ElasticSearch endpoint, if available, or to return an empty string as a placeholder if not.

---

I expect this is written this *specific* way because it was targeting an earlier version of the Terraform language which had fewer features. A different way to write this expression in current Terraform (v0.14 is current as of my writing this) would be:

```
  elastic_search_endpoint = (
    length(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint) > 0 ? module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint : ""
  )
```

It's awkward that this includes the full output reference twice though. That might be justification for using the `concat` approach even in modern Terraform, although arguably the intent wouldn't be so clear to a future reader:

```
  elastic_search_endpoint = (
    concat(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint, "")[0]
  )
```

Modern Terraform also includes the possibility of `null` values, so if I were writing a module like yours today I'd probably prefer to return a null rather than an empty string, in order to be clearer that it's representing the absense of a value:

```
  elastic_search_endpoint = (
    length(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint) > 0 ? module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint : null
  )
```

```
  elastic_search_endpoint = (
    concat(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint, null)[0]
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first: who wrote that code? Why is not documented? Ask the guy!

Just from that code... There's not much to do. I'd say that since `concat` expects two lists, `module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint` is a `list(string)`. Also, depending on some `variable`s, it might be empty. Concatenating an empty string will ensure that there's something at `0` position

So the whole `${element(concat(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint, list("")),0)}` could be translated to `length(module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint) > 0 ? module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint[0] : ""` (which IMHO is much readable)

> Why can't it just be like this?
>
> elastic_search_endpoint = "${module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint}"

Probably because `elastic_search_endpoint` is an `string` and, as mentioned before, `module.es_cluster.elasticsearch_endpoint` is a `list(string)`. You should provide a default value in case the list is empty

Comment: *"Why is not documented?"* - probably because it is not document-worthy. As you say one sentence later *"There's not much to do"*.

Comment: There's not much to do with just that single line of code. We don't know the types of each value!